# Difference between two datetimes not showing in days, it shows me in seconds instead, I have used timezone as IST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

Im working on a small Rails application. I have set my timezone to IST by changing my config file to

```
config.time_zone = 'Kolkata'
```

I have a model which takes a virtual attribute Subscription and converts in into two datetimes valid_from and valid_to, The code is as follows:

```
  def subscription=(value)
    case value
    when "WEEKLY"
    self.valid_from = DateTime.now
        self.valid_to = DateTime.now + 7.days
    when "MONTHLY"
    self.valid_from = DateTime.now
        self.valid_to = DateTime.now >> 1
    when "HALF YEARLY"
    self.valid_from = DateTime.now
        self.valid_to = DateTime.now >> 6
    when "YEARLY"
    self.valid_from = DateTime.now
        self.valid_to = DateTime.now >> 12
    end

  end
```

It stores the values perfectly, but when I retrieve the number of days its giving me wrong days. i have tried it out in console to show the results, Here are the results:

```
irb(main):017:0> x = a.valid_from
=> Wed, 16 Apr 2014 14:15:04 IST +05:30
irb(main):018:0> y = a.valid_to
=> Wed, 23 Apr 2014 14:15:04 IST +05:30
irb(main):019:0> z = DateTime.now
=> Wed, 16 Apr 2014 14:19:07 +0530
irb(main):020:0> w = DateTime.now + 7.days
=> Wed, 23 Apr 2014 14:19:28 +0530
irb(main):021:0> p = (y-x).to_i
=> 604800
irb(main):022:0> q = (w-z).to_i
=> 7
irb(main):023:0> Time.zone
=> (GMT+05:30) Mumbai
```

I can see the difference in times in mine it shows IST + 5:30 and in DateTime.now it just shows +5:30. But I dont know why that is happening. I'm new to rails and if someone could let me know about it I will be very grateful.

Also i tried to decode the value 604800. I guessed that it has to be something x*7 and so I got the value of x to be 86400.

Now 86400 = 24*60*60. This implies I have been getting the value in seconds. Can I know why this is happening? I would like to get it in days.

Comment: Could please check your server time?

Comment: Started GET "/assets/up_arrow.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-16 15:07:48 +0530, Is that what you were asking? If not please excuse my dumbness. Im very new to web development.